# Incomplete installation of WindowBuilder Pro on Juno

Tags: gwt, eclipse-juno

I have installed WindowBuilder Pro package from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201206261200/4.2/) using "Install new software" option from halp menu but there have not been contained any GWT Designer only Swing Designer,SWT Designer and WindowBuilder Engine.And I don't have these two icons in the upper left corner as   [this man](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUL3qEoZkR4) has at 5:30.Can I install GWT separately,or someone has a better idea?

Comment: I have installed GWT separately from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 .I think I have installed the necessary packages but the problem is there is no menu items.

Comment: The man from YouTube says that Juno version is not supported by Google for its WindowBuilder PRO plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Install Eclipse SDK before. It works yes. I'm using here with Juno 4.2. See the guidelines on the plugin page.

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php